# Multiple ssh access types from a given user1/client to the same user2/server

Tags: ssh, rhel, authorization, bazaar

I want to access from one user/client combination (say, `user1@cl`) to a user/server combination (say, `user2@srv`) via ssh, with two different types of Access:

1. Access type #1 would be restricted to interactions with a bazaar repository.
   For this, I added a line (#1) in `~user2/.ssh/authorized_keys` like

   ```
   command="bzr serve --inet --directory=/repodir --allow-writes",no-port-forwarding,no-X11-forwarding,no-agent-forwarding ssh-rsa ... user1@cl
   ```
2. Access type #2 would be a login shell.
   For this, I added a "usual" line (#2) in `~user2/.ssh/authorized_keys` like

   ```
   ssh-rsa ... user1@cl
   ```

As I understand, and as I tested, both lines cannot be used simultaneously.
I.e., if line #1 appears first in `~user2/.ssh/authorized_keys`, then I would be able to interact with the bzr repo, but I will not be able to do

```
[user1@cl]$ ssh user2@srv
```

If line #2 appears first in `~user2/.ssh/authorized_keys`, then I would be able to do `ssh`, but any `bzr` operation gives

```
bzr: ERROR: Not a branch ...
```

**Is there any way to work this out?**

I am using RHEL7, but I guess this is not important.

Related posts (but not addressing my case, as I understand):

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2419566/best-way-to-use-multiple-ssh-private-keys-on-one-client

https://serverfault.com/questions/142997/what-options-can-be-put-into-a-ssh-authorized-keys-file

https://serverfault.com/questions/749474/ssh-authorized-keys-command-option-multiple-commands

https://askubuntu.com/questions/1962/how-can-multiple-private-keys-be-used-with-ssh

Comment: Do ssh-keys are the same for bzr and for login sessions?

Comment: Generate two keys for `user1`, use one for bazaar and the other for shell access.

Comment: @SatōKatsura - Would you mind expanding? I would use two different key pairs. But then, 1) How would the client and the server know which to use? I am not finding this anywhere.

Answer (score 2):

1. On your client machine generate two keys for `user1`, say `/home/user1/key1` and `/home/user1/key2`.  If you don't have particularly strong security concerns you might give an empty password to one of them, say to `key1`.
2. Copy both keys to the server with `ssh-copy-id`:

   ```
   ssh-copy-id -i ~/.ssh/key1 user2@server.example.com
   ssh-copy-id -i ~/.ssh/key2 user2@server.example.com
   ```

   Login with both of them, to make sure they work:

   ```
   ssh -i ~/.ssh/key1 user2@server.example.com
   ssh -i ~/.ssh/key2 user2@server.example.com
   ```
3. On the server edit your `~user2/.ssh/authorized_keys`, and add `command="bzr ..."`  to the first key.
4. Back on the client machine edit a file `~user1/.ssh/config`, and add aliases for both keys.  Something like this:

   ```
   Host alias1
       HostName        server.example.com
       User            user2
       IdentityFile    /home/user1/.ssh/key1
       ControlPath     ~/.ssh/ctl1-%u-%r-%h-%p
       ControlMaster   auto
       ControlPersist  5m

   Host alias2
       HostName        server.example.com
       User            user2
       IdentityFile    /home/user1/.ssh/key2
   ```
5. Now use `bzr+ssh://alias1` for `bazaar`, and `ssh alias2` for a login shell.

Further edit `~/.ssh/config` to suit your needs, the syntax is the same as for `/etc/ssh/ssh_config`.  That's about all.

Comment: This seems to be a nice solution. I will try it and get back.

Answer (score 1):

I made it work, with two different key pairs (say, pair 1 for `bzr` and pair 2 for `ssh` login).
I added the corresponding lines in `~user2/.ssh/authorized_keys`.
The private key 1 was stored in file `id_rsa` (which is read by default), 
and the private key 2 was stored in file `id_rsa_ssh`.

Then, `bzr` was working normally, and for logging in I use

```
[user1@cl]$ ssh -i id_rsa_ssh user2@srv
```

which indicates using an alternative identity.

Comment: You could have one `Host` section as an "alias" for each of the two use cases in `~/.ssh/config`. The sections would point to the same `HostName` but use different `IdentityFile`.